# Trying to create a class that contains an array of structs, that are predefined

Tags: c++

I have a class called CoolMenuItems

```
class CoolMenuItems
{
public:
    CoolMenuItems();
    ~CoolMenuItems();

    struct MenuItemOne
    {
        int id;
        uint32 type;
        uint32 subtype;
        String name;
    };

    struct MenuItemTwo
    {
        uint32 subtype;
        String name;
    };
}
```

This is just the bare bones of the class... I want to have two arrays, one of MenuItemOne, and one of MenuItemTwo, and these arrays would have the following. These arrays I want to initialize like:

```
MenuItemOne a[] =
{
    {1, EQData::EQ_EFFECT_TYPE_PARAMETRIC,       0,                                              T("Parametric")},
    {2, EQData::EQ_EFFECT_TYPE_FILTER_LOW_PASS,  EQData::EQ_FILTER_TYPE_FILTER_BUTTERWORTH_12DB, T("Low Pass")},
};

MenuItemTwo b[] =
{
    {EQData::EQ_FILTER_TYPE_TRHU,                      T("Thru")},
    {EQData::EQ_FILTER_TYPE_BUTTERWORTH_6DB,           T("6  dB Butterworth")},

};
```

only, with more elements than just two...

I want to set it up so that I can create a new CoolMenuItems object with

```
CoolMenuItems *cmi = new CoolMenuItems();
```

so that I can access those array elements via

```
cmi->a[1];
```

Comment: What is the specific question here?  Which part of this is causing you trouble?

Comment: Do you want each CoolMenuItems to have a separate copy of the menu items (maybe so they could be altered) or is there one immutable copy of the menu items that all CoolMenuItems should point to?

Comment: @Oli I can't get my solution to compile... I don't think I'm familiar enough with the language. Specifically, I'm looking for the functionality at the very end of my question, with some sort of implementation.

Comment: @antlersoft I want each copy of CoolMenuItems to have a seperate copy, however there will only be one CoolMenuItem ever. Previously, there was no class at all, and just a static array of structs inside of the source file, however, I had to change that because static memory is allocated before main is executed, and this caused problems in my code... I won't get into it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify your code like this

```
class CoolMenuItems
{
public:
    CoolMenuItems();
    ~CoolMenuItems();

    struct MenuItemOne
    {
        int id;
        uint32 type;
        uint32 subtype;
        String name;
    };

    struct MenuItemTwo
    {
        uint32 subtype;
        String name;
    };
std::vector<MenuItemOne> menuItemOne;
std::vector<MenuItemTwo> menuItemTwo;
}
```

So that you can initialize the elements of struct and push_back the struct into the std::vector, all the memory to be allocated and to be freed will be taken care of by the std::vector

```
MenuItemOne a = {1, EQData::EQ_EFFECT_TYPE_PARAMETRIC, 0,T("Parametric")};

menuItemOne.push_back(a);
```

Similarly for MenuItemTwo.
If you have a different requirement then please give more details.

Comment: This would be a good solution, however You can only initialize that struct once like that. Afterwards you need to manually set elements of the struct before calling push_back.

Comment: why? , please give examples to elaborate. I think you dont need to manually set the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of member variables are somewhat tricky in C++, so my recommendation would be something like the following:

```
MenuItemOne& ret_a(int i)
{
    static MenuItemOne a[] =
    {
        // definition of a[]
    };
    return a[i]; // maybe with some bounds checking
}
```

Note that this has some advantages. First, declaring the array `a` as `static` inside a class method makes it globally defined just once. Second, you hide the actual `a[]` array behind a method call, which is a better design practice.

**EDIT**

As the arrays cannot be static, as the values depend on some other library, the values have to be set up at some point, say the `CoolMenuItems` constructor:

```
CoolMenuItems::CoolMenuItems()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < A_ITEMS; ++i)
    {
       a[i].id = X;
       a[i].name = T("xxx");
    }   
    // ...
}
```

or, if you have to put the values by hand:

```
CoolMenuItems::CoolMenuItems()
{
    a[0].id = X;
    a[0].name = T("xxx");
    a[1].id = ...   
    // ...
}
```

This is tedious, but can be automated with some editor usage, or preprocessor. Note also that you then have to declare the `ret_a` function similarly and declare the corresponding `a` and `b` arrays within the class:

```
MenuItemOne a[A_ITEMS];
MenuItemTwo b[B_ITEMS];
```

With enough time, I'd give you a nice elisp macro to be used within emacs to generate all the initializations from the C arrays you wrote :)

Comment: I cannot make the MenuItem arrays of structs static, as they contain Strings from the JUCE library, which must be translated using a specific macro which relies on the JUCE application to be set up, however static memory of objects is allocated before main() is executed so this is causing me grief...

Comment: @Colton, if this is the case, you have to initialize the values programatically, say, in the constructor of the class, because these arrays, either static or not, have to be initialized with constant data. I'm editing my answer with this knowledge.

Comment: @Colton: globals and class static members are initialized before `main`, but the local static variable @Diego recommended won't be initialized until the first time `ret_a()` gets called.

Comment: Hmm.... is there no way whatsoever to have an initialization of those arrays in the nice clean way that I showed earlier? Before I made this class, I was simply using a static global array inside the source file... Couldn't I somehow just have a non static array initialized in the source home how? Global scope would make sense for this...